# Shell interface Hippo

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

Did anybody use the shell interface of Hippo (JCR Repository over rmi)?

Comment: I'm sure someone uses it somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean: http://forge.onehippo.org/projects/jcr-shell/? I do use it and find it very useful from time to time. But I may be a bit biased because I wrote it.. ;-)